# Social Plugins - Internet Explorer Error

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I am attempting to integrate simple follow buttons for FB, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google+ into my website footer (www.achieveglobal.com - currently the production site only has links, not plugins)
The code generated in each platform works perfectly in both chrome and firefox (of course).

However, in IE (all versions from what I can tell), although the buttons display without issue, I am getting an error when I try to follow FB, LinkedIn and Google+.  Twitter works fine.

When the button is clicked, IE opens a second window (which seems to be trying to either have the user sign in or initiate the "follow").  But instead, I get an IE popup that says "the webpage you are viewing is trying to close the window, do you want to close the window" with a Y/N selection.  Selecting yes or no doesn't matter, either way the follow is not completed.

Is this a code issue or an issue with IE security settings?  Code below:

```
<ul class="social-list">
    <li><script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US
</script> <script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="162260" data-counter="right"></script></li>
    <li>
    <div data-share="false" data-show-faces="false" data-action="like" data-layout="button_count" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/AchieveGlobal" class="fb-like"></div>
    </li>
    <li><a data-lang="en" data-show-screen-name="false" data-show-count="true" class="twitter-follow-button" href="https://twitter.com/achieveglobal">Follow @twitterapi</a>      <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script></li>
    <li><div class="g-follow" data-annotation="bubble" data-height="15" data-href="https://plus.google.com/105395720126535169711" data-rel="publisher">&nbsp;</div>
    <!-- Place this tag after the last widget tag. --> <script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })(); 
</script></li>
</ul>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like the popup is being opened so that the site can create first-party cookies and some IE security setting is messing with things.

Comment: Try playing around with different IE security settings to see which ones are causing the issue, then you can start searching for info about that issue and how to work around it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the buttons of each company:

Linkedin - http://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company

Google + - https://developers.google.com/+/web/follow/?hl=pt

Twitter - https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#follow

Facebook - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/follow-button/

Comment: so, no problem anymore ?